# Good pattern to write OpenLayers 4 javascript plugins

Tags: openlayers

I am writing an OpenLayers 4 plugin, and would love to follow the approach of some existing OL plugin library. Is there a recommended/good quality example of an OpenLayers 4 plugin that I can model my code on? The code that lives outside of the main OL repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain a couple of OpenLayers plugins which I've recently updated to be compatible with the `ol` package. I found that using https://rollupjs.org/ has worked out pretty well.

Both plugins are small but take a look at the source of https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-popup as an example. Things to note:

- The source JavaScript in [`src/ol-popup.js`](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-popup/blob/master/src/ol-popup.js) imports it's dependencies from the `ol` package and exports a single `Popup` class.
- `src/ol-popup.js` is transformed by rollup (see [`build` script in `package.json`](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-popup/blob/master/package.json#L19) and [`rollup.config.js`](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-popup/blob/master/rollup.config.js).

  - Rollup converts the code to plain JS and wraps everything in a UMD which allows you to use the plugin directly in the browser via a script tag via `require` or es6 `import` in your application. The transformed code is in the `dist` directory.
  - The interesting parts of `rollup.config.js` are:

    - The `external` function which tells Rollup to treat the `ol` modules as external to the build (so they don't get included in `dist/ol-popup.js`)
    - The `globals` object maps the es6 module names to the "dotted" equivalent in a full hosted OpenLayers build.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why someone's down-voted the question and all answers. Seems a legit question to me...

Answer (score 1):

OL Extensions has quite a few examples of different interactions written as individual extensions: https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins on the official [third party library](https://openlayers.org/3rd-party/) page.

A few suggestions when writing your own plugin:

- OpenLayers functionality can be extended in many ways, so there is no general pattern.
- You can create custom controls and interactions by either subclassing an existing one, or by configuring `ol/interaction/Interaction` or `ol/control/Control` with handler functions that your plugin could provide.
- You can extend layer sources in many ways, e.g. by providing custom `tileUrlFunction` or `tileLoadFunction` functions.
- Your plugin could hook into any of the numerous events that OpenLayers components emit.
- OpenLayers 4+ is provided as a set of ES modules (https://npmjs.com/package/ol), so you do not need to worry about packaging. Application developers will import what they need from OpenLayers and from your plugin.
- It is good practice to only use features of OpenLayers that are listed in the [API documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/).

Comment: at the moment I'm using a build step to create a UMD bundle and support use with the full hosted build, in future do you expect everyone to use the `ol` package and es6?

Comment: I also still provide a full build of my plugins that can be used with a full build of OpenLayers. But I‘m confident we‘ll see more and more developers use modules with bundlers to create a single js file with all library and application code.